# Convert section of code from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am attempting to convert this function from `matlab` to `C#`

What is the equivalent `C#` of these `matlab` statements? The `C#` portion below shows the section of `matlab` code that I don't understand how to port to `C#`

```matlab
   res(res == 0) = p * scale * unit(res == 0);
   W = min(unit, scale * p * (abs(res)).^ (-1));
```

The whole `matlab` section, and my attempt to port it

```matlab
function W = huber(res, scale, param)
% function W = huber(res, scale, param)
%
% computes Huber's weight function for robust regression:
% min( 1, param/(|res|/scale) )
% 
% arguments:
%       res:    vector of residuals
%       scale:  robust estimate of scale, such as MAD
%       param:  parameter of the Huber function; the
%           default value is 2.5.
%
% returns:
%       W:  the vector of Huber weights
%
%
% P.B. Stark  stark@stat.berkeley.edu
% 9 July 1997.

p = 2.5;        % default parameter
if (nargin == 3),
    if (param > 0),
        p = param;
    else
        error('parameter must be positive')
    end
end

unit = ones(size(res));
res(res == 0 ) = p*scale*unit(res==0);
W = min(unit, scale*p*(abs(res)).^(-1));
return;
```

C# code.

```
public static double Hueber(double[] residuals, double scale, double param)
{
        //Calculation of the mean estimate for a given range using Huber's weights
        //The Huber's function is defined as min( 1, param/(|residuals|/scale))
        //param: a given parameter - affects the range where weights = 1
        //residuals: deviation from the mean estimate (I used the median as the first approximation)
        //scale: estimate of variation. Some use 1.483*(median absolute deviation, or MAD,
        // of the deviations of the data from their median). I used std, i.e. dblAveVar
        //See http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/Preprints/Oersted/writeup.htm

        double p = 2.5;        //default parameter
        if (param > 0)
            p = param;
        else
            throw new Exception("parameter must be positive");

        double[] unit = Ones(residuals.Length);

        // What is the C# of this?
        //res(res == 0) = p * scale * unit(res == 0);
        //W = min(unit, scale * p * (abs(res)).^ (-1));

        return W;
    }

    public static double[] Ones(int length)
    {
        double[] ones = new double[length];

        ones.Populate(1.0);

        return ones;
    }
```

Comment: Would be easier if you say what the code should do.

Comment: Btw your default parameter value serves no purpose. The value of `p` will always be overriden by `param` OR an exception with be thrown which is not the case in the original code which has an extra check based on the value of `nargin` (absent here)

Comment: From reviewing the matlab docs `res(res==0)=X` says to set all indexes of res where the value of res at that index is zero to X. So iterate through res and if the value is zero then replace the value with the formula on the right. unit(res==0) says indexes of unit  where the corresponding index in res has a value of zero. **I think**. I know nothing about Matlab other than quickly reviewing their docs. You'd have to know how matlab deals with multiplying vectors and taking absolute value as well. Ultimately I think it's going to be a pretty iterative solution.

Comment: Woa, that is pretty convoluted code for 2 statements ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//res(res == 0) = p * scale * unit(res == 0);
//W = min(unit, scale * p * (abs(res)).^ (-1));
```

Code is given below;

```
public static double Hueber(double[] residuals, double scale, double param)
{
  double p = 2.5;        //default parameter
  if (param > 0)
     p = param;
  else
     throw new Exception("parameter must be positive");

  for ( int i = 0; i < residuals.Length ; i++) {
     if ( residuals[i] == 0) {
         residuals[i] = p * scale * 1;  // res(res == 0 ) = p*scale*unit(res==0)
     }
     // Then we can do smae step in this loop W = min(unit, scale*p*(abs(res)).^(-1))
     residuals[i] = Math.Min(1, scale*p*Math.Abs(1/residuals[i]));
  }

  return residuals; // w = residuals[]
  }
```